# Can't change MySQL port in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mysql

I have been trying for hours and can't find what the issue is.

```
vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

>

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/ 
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

[mysqld] 
port=3444

[client] 
user=root 
password=test123 
port=3444
```

And the next file:

```
vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

>

```
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3444
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
# bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
```

Then I do a restart:

```
systemctl restart mysql.service
```

But in mysql console, I still see this. Same in `systemctl status mysql`

```
mysql> show variables like '%port%';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| innodb_support_xa        | ON    |
| large_files_support      | ON    |
| port                     | 3306  |
| report_host              |       |
| report_password          |       |
| report_port              | 3306  |
| report_user              |       |
| require_secure_transport | OFF   |
+--------------------------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Plz try this : in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, remove all but the 2 first lines with includes

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it. It made no difference. The port still shows at 3306

Comment: that's strange. i just tested it on a out-of-the-box mysql on 18.04 and its ok : new port after unit restart...

Comment: I found the reason.  I had this line in my installation script: `chmod 600 /etc/mysql/my.cnf` The moment I do that and restart the service, the port goes back to default.  I thought this is important to increase security. I guess I shouldn't do it after all.